# Is point inside a circle sector

Tags: math, geometry

I need help on how to determine if a point "D" is inside a circle sector of 180°, known radius & center "B". As for the direction of the sector I don't know how to explain it with words so I made a sketch but basically it depends on another point "A".

[image: sketch]

An explanation would be good enough but I'm not very good at maths so if you could give me a pseudocode it would be perfect!

Thanks !

Comment: It is called a sector, not a cone. Here's an answer maybe could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675772/3807365

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. And do you have any additional information to give  for the sectorStart/sectorEnd ?

Comment: see [Generate a "pieslice" in C without using the pieslice() of graphics.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246614/2521214)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the angle ψ below, to test if it is within certain limits (like +/- 90°)

[image: fig1]

This can be done by [finding the angle **ψ** between the vectors **B**-**A** and  **D**-**B**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486462/380384).

The angle between them is found using the following dot and cross product rules

[image: fig2]      [image: fig3]

and the pseudocode using the `atan2(dy,dx)` function that must programming environments have

```
v_1.x = B.x-A.x
v_1.y = B.y-A.y
v_2.x = D.x-B.x
v_2.y = D.y-B.y

ψ = atan2( (v_1.x*v_2.y - v_1.y*v_2.x), (v_1.x*v_2.x + v_1.y*v_2.y) )
```

Note that the result is within `-π` and `+π` covering all 4 quadrants

Now just check if `abs(ψ) <= π/2`.

<sub>Take a note of the definition of `atan2` since some environments define it as `atan2(dx,dy)` and some as `atan2(dy,dx)`, where the angle is measured such that `dx=r*cos(ψ)` and `dy=r*sin(ψ)`.</sub>

And don't forget to check also the distance **BD** if it's within the radius of the circle.

Comment: That looks like a solved question, thanks!

Comment: Other answers might come also, but in my opinion the above is the simplest and it avoids taking any square roots and the complexities that arise from complementary angles.

Comment: goniometrics is not needed for this at all ...