# Equation of sector of a circle

Tags: geometry, coordinates

As there is equation for circle such as
(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2 where center(h,k) and redius r.

Is there any equation for sector of circle like that?

As there is equation for circle such as
(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2 where center(h,k) and redius r.

Is there any equation for sector of circle like that?

Comment: There is no single equation for sector. Equation of circle + some description of angle limits.

Comment: see [Generate a "pieslice" in C without using the pieslice() of graphics.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246614/2521214)